# srlua makefile error lua.h No such file or directory

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, lua, makefile

I'm trying to use `srlua` to compile my lua files to executables but I've ran into a problem.

```
anthony@anthony-linux:~/Downloads/srlua$ make
gcc -I/tmp/lhf/lua-5.2.0/src -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O2    -c -o srlua.o srlua.c
srlua.c:19:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [srlua.o] Error 1
```

I'm running linux 64bit (ubuntu)

EDIT: I tried changing the settings of my makefile but now I get this

```
anthony@anthony-linux:~/Downloads/srlua$ sudo make
gcc -I/usr/local/include -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O2    -c -o srlua.o srlua.c
srlua.c:19:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [srlua.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited in some basic formatting to make the question clearer and easier to read.

Comment: You're not using the latest version of srlua for Lua 5.1. See http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#srlua.

Comment: i fixed that Thanks for pointing out. it still doesn’t work though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I doubt that `sudo` will help. The issue is that GCC can't locate `lua.h`, which implies that you haven't told it where to find the developer files needed to compile programs that link against the Lua core. You likely need to identify a folder such as `/usr/local/lua/include`.

It is also likely that you have the Lua executable package installed, but not the developer package. If so, you will need to locate and install that package. A command like

```
$ apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev
```

does that for Lua 5.1.

If you are building Lua 5.2 from source, then you have all the files you need, you just need to tell srlua's makefile where to find them.

I've successfully built and used srlua on Windows with Lua 5.1, but have not needed to try this on Ubuntu yet, so I can't be a whole lot more specific.

**Update:**

From your pastebin, try this:

```
# these will probably work if Lua has been installed globally
LUA= /usr/include/lua5.1
LUAINC= /usr/include/lua5.1
LUALIB= /usr/lib/lua/5.1
LUABIN= /usr/bin
```

You had typo in the definition of `$(LUAINC)`. You will need to locate liblua.a and name the right folder in the definition of `$(LUALIB)`. I don't have the lua dev packages installed on my handy Ubuntu box, so I'm not certain where it got put.

**Update 2:** You are getting closer, since you have got past the compiler configuration and into the linker configuration issues.

On my Ubuntu box, Lua's library appears to be `/usr/lib/liblua5.1.a`, and there is no file named `liblua.a`. So for me `-llua` cannot work. I was able to compile a simplest possible "hello world"...

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dostring(L, "print('hello, '.._VERSION)");
    return 0;
}
```

with the command

```
$ gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -o hello hello.c -llua5.1 -lm
$ ./hello
hello, Lua 5.1
$
```

Perhaps you should make a similar minimal example work, then go back to tweaking the `srlua` makefile.

Comment: For me the only file i can find with lua is /usr/include/lua5.1/ and it has lauxlib.h lua.h luaconf.h lualib.h lua.hpp

Comment: So, arrange for the makefile to say `-I/usr/include/lua5.1` and try again. You are likely to need to do a similar exercise looking for the right folder to name in a `-L` option so that `-llua` will work for linking.

Comment: here is my makefile http://pastebin.com/MgGDSujq That gives me the same error as before. Sorry im new to linux and all that jazz.

Comment: Updated. You had a typo which wasn't helping.

Comment: OOPS SORRY ABOUT THAT. I found where liblua.a is and its at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. So I put it under where it says LUALIB and now i get this error gcc -o srlua -Wl,-E srlua.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llua -lm -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [srlua] Error 1

Comment: I suspect you have liblua5.1.a, not liblua.a. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. My program that I wrote is very small so I guess i'll just rewrite it in python or something. Sorry to waste your time I thought it would be easier then this. thanks for the help

Comment: 'apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev' did it for me

Comment: Though my system already had lua5.1 and lua5.2, installing lua5.3 and lua5.3-dev fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This has been like this for at least 5 years now. Why doesn't lua get installed in a way that GCC finds it? I think LibBullet is the same.

Comment: does anyone knows how to get `lua.h` found on MacOS ?