# Node.js and Travis CI: can't find lua.h when installing node-lua package

Tags: node.js, github, build, lua, travis-ci

I've been trying for about a week or so now to work out how to get this Travis CI build to pass.

I'm using package called [node-lua](https://github.com/South-Paw/node-lua-updated) (this is my own fork of it, was hoping some other forks might have contained a fix) for part of an update script.

Every run of the script results in the same error and despite looking at other [repos](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass/blob/master/.travis.yml) that use lua and [other](https://github.com/victorliu/S4/issues/45) [issues](https://github.com/victorliu/S4/issues/46) [on](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass/blob/master/.travis.yml) [the](https://github.com/moteus/lua-travis-example) [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079572/srlua-makefile-error-lua-h-no-such-file-or-directory), I'm still at a loss on how to get this build to pass.

Here is some of the travis ci output, a full log can be found [here](https://travis-ci.org/South-Paw/warframe-item-list/builds/429509167) and the PR that this is being an issue on is [here](https://github.com/South-Paw/warframe-item-list/pull/40)

```
make: Entering directory `/home/travis/build/South-Paw/warframe-item-list/node_modules/node-lua-updated/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodelua/src/utils.o
In file included from ../src/utils.cc:2:0:
../src/utils.h:8:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
 #include <lua.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodelua/src/utils.o] Error 1
```

I'm at an absolute loss and pretty much at wits end with this - someone please save me from this misery even if it is so painfully obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes across this in the future, here's the PR solved the issue.

https://github.com/South-Paw/warframe-item-list/pull/41/files